# Detect that I am in chrome app/extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I somehow detect my code is running in Chrome App/Extension?

I need that, because I am writing a library and I need to work around one corner-case.

Using third-party npm packages for this is OK, but I haven't find any.

Comment: I have voted to close my own question as duplicate, since I don't want to delete it outright (maybe people will find it better using my title through google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found is a little hacky, and that is

```
function isChromeApp() {
    return chrome != null && chrome.runtime != null && chrome.runtime.getManifest != null;
}
```

Comment: It's not really hacky, it's close to optimal. To highlight, this will detect **both extensions and apps**.